# Serial monitor problem instantly finishing

Tags: arduino-ide

```
int pinRed=2;
int pinBlue=4;
int pinWhite=6;
String Color;
String question="Which LED would you like to light up Red,Blue or White?";
int delayTime=1000;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(pinRed,OUTPUT);
pinMode(pinBlue,OUTPUT);
pinMode(pinWhite,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
Serial.print(question);
while(Serial.available()==0){
  
}
Color=Serial.readString();
  if(Color=="Red" || Color=="red"){
    digitalWrite(pinRed,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(pinBlue,LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinWhite,LOW);
    delay(delayTime);
  }
  if(Color=="Blue" || Color=="blue"){
    digitalWrite(pinBlue,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(pinRed,LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinWhite,LOW);
    delay(delayTime);
  }
  if(Color=="White" || Color=="white"){
    digitalWrite(pinWhite,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(pinBlue,LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinRed,LOW);
    delay(delayTime);
  }
  delay(delayTime);
}
```

This is my code, but is not working, when I enter a color the serial monitor ask the question again instantly and not led is turning on, I checked the pins and the LEDs work completely fine but I think I have a problem with my serial monitor cause I am having problem with every project using the serial monitor despite even copying codes from the internet, so anyone have any idea what can be the problem(I am on version Arduino 1.8.18)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure as I am not familiar with the particular language/library that you are using.  However, the symptoms you describe indicate that your input string does not match any of your targets ('red', 'RED') etc.

I would re-read the description of the Serial.available() function.  Is it returning non-zero as soon as the first character is available? If so then your input string from
`Color=Serial.readString()`  will always be aone-character string, eg 'r'.

To test this you could try matching against 'r', 'g', 'b' as strings.....